# How to parse? top down parsing not possible?

Tags: parsing

We have to parse this two words:

```
"abccdef"
"cabddc"
```

but with:

```
S->aBC
B->b|dc
C->aD
D-ac
```

?? How is it possible to parse this words with that? Is that a misstake in the task?

Comment: It takes like 10min to code that parser - so try it. (my attempt shows, that it is indeed not parsing either of the input strings.) I assumed that `D->ac` and the lack of `>` is just a typo.

Answer (score 0):

As posted in my comment above, if in doubt, code it.
Of course, you can see that the characters `e` and `f` are not part of the parser rules and as such, it is kind of obvious.

Unless, of course, I misunderstood your `D` production rule. This is one reason, why you should always explain a bit more about your problem. The `D-ac` might be a local convention for something, the majority of people here cannot interpret. I considered it a typo, meaning the same as `D->ac`.

Here is how it looks in Common Lisp:

```lisp
(defun parser (s &optional (n (length s)) (i 0) (state :s))
  (when i
    (if (= i n)
    i
    (let ((c (char s i)))
      (ecase state
        (:s
         (when (char-equal c #\a)
           (parser s n (parser s n (+ i 1) :b) :c)))
        (:b
         (when (and (or (char-equal c #\b) (char-equal c #\d))
            (< (+ i 1) n)
            (char-equal (char s (+ i 1)) #\c))
           (+ i 2)))
        (:c
         (when (char-equal c #\a)
           (parser s n (+ i 1) :d)))
        (:d
         (when (and (char-equal c #\a)
            (< (+ i 1) n)
            (char-equal (char s (+ i 1)) #\c))
           (+ i 2))))))))
```

I use the symbols `:s`, `:b`, `:c` and `:d` as state information (which production rule is the current state of the program).

Translated to pleb, which might be a language you have seen before, it looks like this (I only had pleb 3.9 and so there is no switch case syntax in that language, since someone added it later in version 3.10. My version also has no enum built into the language, so I just misused a class for that.):

```py
class State:
    S = 1
    B = 2
    C = 3
    D = 4

def parser(s,i=0,state=State.S):
    n=len(s)
    if i == n:
        return i
    else:
        c = s[i]
        if state == State.S:
            if c == 'a':
                return parser(s,
                              parser(s,i+1,State.B),
                              State.C)
        elif state == State.B:
            if (c == 'b' or c == 'd') and (i+1)<n and s[i+1]== 'c':
                return i+2
        elif state == State.C:
            if c == 'a':
                return parser(s,i+1,State.D)
        elif state == State.D:
            if c == 'a' and (i+1)<n and s[i+1] == 'c':
                return i+2
        else:
            raise ValueError("Unknown parser state!")
```

Running either of the above, with your given strings, they return `NIL` or nothing, respectively and if you run it with an input, which conforms to the grammar, e.g. `"abcaac" or "adcaac"`, you get the length of the input as return value.